# C++, reading letters from a file

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following code, but it only reads lowercase letters.  Ideally, it would read both upper and lower case letters and then store this info in an array.  Any help  or suggestions would be welcome.

Cheers.

Comment: Yeah it is, sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: This program is probably going out of bounds on `letterCount` if the input file does not consist of all lowercase letters. Also why is `letterCount[int(letter)-'a']++;` in its own scope?

Comment: Upper case A is '65' and lower case a is '97', so if int(letter)-'a' is negative use '65'

Comment: @EmmanuelN: Try that again, what you said doesn't match your code at all.  Also, the scope is the `{}`.  Why is that there?

Comment: Also, if you won't use containers, at least wrap array accesses in an `assert`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with the code above but to answer your question directly, simply do some kind of check before incrementing the letterCount

```
if ( letter >= 'a' )
   letterCount[int(letter)-'a']++;
else
   letterCount[int(letter)-'A']++;
```

IMPORTANT:

This is not initializing the array to zeros, its just setting the first item to zero then the rest are garbage.

```
int letterCount[26] = {0};
```

to set the whole array to zero you have to iterate with a for loop and set each one to 0, manually type it out like {0, 0, 0, 26 times ... }, or use memset() to clear it all at once.

Comment: Actually `int letterCount[26] = {0};` does set all the elements to 0. Elements whose values are not specified are value initialised (or is it default-initialised? doesn't matter either way for `int`), which for `int` is `0`.

Comment: Cheers, this almost solved my problem, just had to tweak it slightly.

Comment: I believe that depends on your compiler and compiler options. I say its best to be deliberate and safe.

Comment: @Alturis nope, it's specified in the C++ standard. It doesn't vary from compiler to compiler. This: `int letterCount[26];` would be bad and filled with random values, but both `int letterCount[26] = {};` and `int letterCount[26] = {0};` initialises all the elements to 0.

Comment: +1 I find it interesting though that `'b' > 'A'` and also `'b' > 'C'`. I wonder how this comes into play when ordering strings with capitalized words and non-capitalized words.

Comment: @Shredder all lowercase letters are less than all uppercase letters because of how they designed ASCII.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I understand that. And I think that should be the case when comparing the ascii values of such characters, but when comparing them as type `char` or `string`, you would think `C` should be greater than `b` due to b's precedence in the alphabet and for ordering purposes. That's all I was saying. But looks like it is left up to the programmer to figure it out^^

Comment: @Shredder well when you compare a `char` you are comparing the ascii values of the characters since that's all a `char` stores. Also, `string` just uses `<` of `char`, so it also compares the ascii values. It would to write a custom predicate though that would put things in the order you're talking about, so yeah, it's pretty much left up to the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not relevant to your task at hand, but you may find it interesting to note that in C++11 you can do the same thing with less code:

```
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[])
{
    std::map<char,int> counts;
    std::ifstream test("test.txt");
    if( test ) {
        std::for_each(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(test),
                      std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
                      [&counts](char c) { if( std::isalpha(c) ) ++counts[c]; });
    }
}
```

The code above fills in a map rather than a vector. In this case for a particular letter a map is slower to access than a vector. You could use a vector rather than a map, but that would add more background processing code, things that are not relevant to the task. I'd probable just copy the map into a vector at the end if you must.

In the previous standard you could still get the same thing done, only you'd replace the lambda function with a function object. That would add maybe 3 lines of code.

Comment: Now this is one of those things I need to start beating into my head that C++11 can do.